# Auto-delete Max/Min from Array on creation

Tags: php, arrays, operators, max, min

Updated Code that creates array, but ISNT outputting the min/max values. **Why isnt this working and how do I get it to automatically remove the min/max value and then reoutput the array?**

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=thekey&country=US&q=nintendo+wii';

$data = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$product_result = curl_exec($data);
curl_close($data);


$arr = json_decode($product_result, true);
$prices = array();

echo "Original Values";

foreach ($arr['items'] as $item)
{
    if (isset($item['product']['inventories'][0]['price']))
    {
        $prices[] = $item['product']['inventories'][0]['price'];
    }
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($prices);
echo '<br /><br />';

// Get the values
$min = $prices[$minIndex];
$max = $prices[$maxIndex];

// Find the values
$minIndex = array_search($min, $prices);
$maxIndex = array_search($max, $prices);

#print out results with no min/max pair
echo $prices[$min] . 'max is ' . $prices[$max];
echo '</pre>';
// Unset the values
unset($prices[$minIndex], $prices[$maxIndex]);
?>
```

Current Output of the code that doesn't seem to show the min/max value:

```
Original Values
Array
(
    [0] => 149.99
    [1] => 149.99
    [2] => 149.99
    [3] => 209.95
    [4] => 124.99
    [5] => 225.99
    [6] => 149.96
    [7] => 249.99
    [8] => 193.99
    [9] => 149.99
    [10] => 149.99
    [11] => 149.99
    [12] => 326.99
    [13] => 269.96
    [14] => 258.99
    [15] => 129.99
    [16] => 149.99
    [17] => 39.99
    [18] => 149.99
    [19] => 209.99
    [20] => 349.95
    [21] => 357.38
    [22] => 169.96
    [23] => 125
    [24] => 149.99
)


max is
```

Comment: one way: unset($prices[array_search($minval)]);unset($prices[array_search($maxval)])

Comment: I saw this unset way but only saw key examples on php.net. Anyway to then reset the array in order to run the next line being: `echo "min is ". $minval . "<br>Max is ". $maxval . "<br />avg is " . $avgofval ;`
  it still appears to be calculating on the initial array with orig max/min pair.

Answer (score 1):

Based on `unset` and `array_search` from php.net, this should work:

```
// Find the values
$minIndex = array_search($minVal, $prices);
$maxIndex = array_search($maxVal, $prices);

// Get the values
$min = $prices[$minIndex];
$max = $prices[$maxIndex];

// Unset the values
unset($prices[$minIndex], $prices[$maxIndex]);

// Print out values
echo 'min value: '.$min;
echo 'max value: '.$max;

// Print full array
print_r($prices);
```

Comment: @Dagon Sorry, I published my answer before I saw your comment.

Comment: this provides a warning that: array_search accepts 2 or more parameters?

Comment: Please see updated code and errors I'm getting. I appreciate it Jon/Dagon!

Comment: This gets rid of the warning, but now it is not finding and getting rid of the `min/max` of the originally fetched array values. How do I get it to display these original `min/max` values, but then output the `array` WITHOUT the `min/max` original values?

Comment: Are you trying to `echo $prices[$min]`? Because all you have to do is `echo $min`, since it has the value already.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be outputting any values?

Answer (score 0):

You may sort the array in numeric order and then use array_pop() and array_shift()

```
  sort($prices,SORT_NUMERIC);
  $maxval    = array_pop($prices);
  $minval    = array_shift($prices);

  $avgofval  = (count($prices))
                 ? array_sum($prices)/count($prices)
                 : 0;

  echo "min is ". $minval . "<br>Max is ". $maxval . "<br />avg is " . $avgofval ;
  echo '<pre>'.print_r($prices,1).'</pre>';
```

Comment: That requires 3 statements, your approach requires 5(2 for finding the values using min/max, 2 for finding the keys and 1 for deleting the values)

Comment: My approach is split up for reading purposes, I could do the entire thing as a one-liner, but there really isn't a point to showing that.

Comment: No matter how many lines you will use, you will still need 5 function-calls,

Answer (score 0):

`$minVal` and `$maxVal` are not defined before the array search call.

```
// Find the values
$minIndex = array_search($minVal, $prices);
$maxIndex = array_search($maxVal, $prices);
```

And array_search doesn't find any value. It find the keys: *Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.*

`$minIndex` is `FALSE`, and `$maxIndex` is also `FALSE`.

The values are also incorrect...

```
// Get the values
$min = $prices[$minIndex]; // $min = $prices[FALSE]
$max = $prices[$maxIndex]; // $max = $prices[FALSE]
```

A possible solution is:

```
$minValue = FALSE;
$maxValue = 0;
foreach ($arr['items'] as $item) {
    if (isset($item['product']['inventories'][0]['price']) !== false) {
        $price = $item['product']['inventories'][0]['price'];
        $prices[] = $price;
        if ( ! $minValue || $minValue < $price) {
            $minValue = $price;
        }
        if ($price > $maxValue) {
            $maxValue = $price;
        }
    }
}
```

Aside

```
if (isset($item['product']['inventories'][0]['price']) !== false) { ... }
```

is a redundant test. It's exactly the same as

```
if (isset($item['product']['inventories'][0]['price'])) { ... }
```

Comment: This doesnt do much. Please see updated code. I appreciate your reply