# Remove the Max/Min From Array, Take Average, Output Average

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=thekey&country=US&q=nintendo+wii';

$data = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$product_result = curl_exec($data);
curl_close($data);


$arr = json_decode($product_result, true);
$prices = array();

echo "Original Values";

foreach ($arr['items'] as $item)
{
    if (isset($item['product']['inventories'][0]['price']))
    {
        $prices[] = $item['product']['inventories'][0]['price'];
    }
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($prices);
echo '<br /><br />';

// Get the values
$min = $prices[$minIndex];
$max = $prices[$maxIndex];

// Find the values
$minIndex = array_search($min, $prices);
$maxIndex = array_search($max, $prices);

#print out results with no min/max pair
echo $prices[$min] . 'max is ' . $prices[$max];
echo '</pre>';
// Unset the values
unset($prices[$minIndex], $prices[$maxIndex]);
?>
```

I have the following code, and currently its outputting:
Original Values

```
Array
(
    [0] => 199.95
    [1] => 149.99
    [2] => 129.99
    [3] => 149.99
    [4] => 149.99
    [5] => 124.99
    [6] => 225.99
    [7] => 149.96
    [8] => 149.99
    [9] => 149.99
    [10] => 184.99
    [11] => 199.99
    [12] => 184.98
    [13] => 149.99
    [14] => 326.99
    [15] => 269.96
    [16] => 348.95
    [17] => 108.9
    [18] => 149.99
    [19] => 149.99
    [20] => 229.99
    [21] => 357.38
    [22] => 169.96
    [23] => 229.98
    [24] => 187.99
)


max is
```

It should be removing the array key [21] and [17] since they arethe max and min. then taking the average WITHOUT these two values and displaying it.

How do I get this to do this?

Comment: You asked this basic question already, and it has a number of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468871/auto-delete-max-min-from-array-on-creation/8468910#8468910

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. sort the array ([`sort`](http://php.net/sort))
2. remove the first element ([`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift))
3. remove the last element ([`array_pop`](http://php.net/array_pop))
4. create the sum of the remaining array ([`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum))
5. divide the sum with the number of elements in the remaining array ([`count`](http://php.net/count)).

Code example:

```
sort($prices, SORT_NUMERIC);
array_shift($prices);
array_pop($prices);
$sum = array_sum($prices);
$average = $sum / count($prices);
```

Comment: Thanks for the steps. How do I go about sorting based on value though. The http://us.php.net/sort link you gave me shows examples of sorting alphabetically, but not numerically.

Comment: You can use the `SORT_NUMERIC` flag for that. I added a code example that shows it.

Comment: Hakre, appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`sort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), [`array_shift`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php), and [`array_pop`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

```
sort($prices); // Sort the array from lowest to highest value
array_pop($prices); // Remove the max value. Use $max = array_pop($prices); if you want to use the value
array_shift($prices); // Remove the min value. Use $min = array_shift($prices); if you want to use the value

echo array_sum($prices)/count($prices); // Echo the average without $max or $min
```

Comment: Where is `array_average` defined?

Answer (score -1):

You could also use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php), [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

```
echo (array_sum($prices) - max($prices) - min($array)) / count($prices);
```

Comment: This answer is inaccurate/incorrect because the original count is used for the averaging (the min and max elements are not "removed").